# Auto-hide OS X menu bar?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

Is there a way to auto-hide the OS X menu bar, like is possible with the Dock?

There was an application "Menufela" that did this for Tiger, but I'm not aware of anything similar for Leopard/Snow Leopard..

I'm almost certain this is (programatically) doable, because in full-screen applications the menu bar is hidden, and reappears when you mouse the mouse is at the top of the screen..

**Edit**: With the help of Steve Folly's answer, the following code:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication]
     setPresentationOptions:   NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideMenuBar
                             | NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideDock];
```

..will auto-hide the menubar (and the dock, as mandated by the API), but only for the current application:

> When controlling or disabling features of Mac OS X system using SetSystemUIMode the requested behaviors are only in effect while the process which called SetSystemUIMode is frontmost

..close, but not quite there

Comment: apple don't have a hide function available for menu bar, as I  know

Comment: There's no option in the System Preferences or wherever, but open a video in Quicktime Player X, make it full screen and move the mouse to the top of the screen. That's the behaviour I'd like, and I'm sure there is a way to trigger this globally (via a private Cocoa API or similar)

Comment: Perhaps this might be better at home over at Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Jasarien - possibly. Even though I gave an answer worthy of being on stackoverflow, I suspect dbr was looking for a way to do this via a preference or something similar.

Comment: Asked a related question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551453/auto-hide-the-os-x-menu-bar-system-wide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MagicMenu it hides the menubar (and dock) per application and also finder if you wish

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I'm looking for! Only problem is, it modifies the Info.plist within the application bundle which means if used on official-Apple applications, they cannot access Keychain.. Many of the applications I use (Finder/Safari/Mail) would become quite annoying without keychain.. Ah well..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good starting point: [Technical Note TN2062](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2002/tn2062.html) about Kiosk applications. But [this article](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/Carbon64BitGuide/HIToolboxChanges/HIToolboxChanges.html) talks about it SetSystemUIMode being a Carbon API with no Cocoa equivalent.

However, digging a bit further, I found [this article](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKit.html) for Snow Leopard which describes NSApplication presentationOptions - the Cocoa replacement for SetSystemUIMode.

Comment: It's not a replacement, it's a wrapper that calls it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Present Your Apps does it as well: http://www.eternalstorms.at/utilities/presentyourapps/

Comment: Looks perfect, but does this work with the built-in applications that use the Keychain, like Mail? Sounds like it might modify the Info.plist which would make the integrity checks fail and mean Mail/etc couldn't use the Keychain, although I'm not sure

Comment: That might explain my Keychain troubles of late!

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, install [Menu Eclipse](http://www.xybernic.com/).

Comment: Does this autohide the bar, or dim it? Looks like v1 is a semitransparent overlay, although v2 looks like it autohides also